# How to get summary count in phtml file?

Tags: magento2.3

I want summary count in .phtml file with cache enable.

Comment: where u want to get summery count, means product page or category page etc...?

Comment: I want summary count in footer same like header.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should get it with customer data. You can try to add the following code in your phtml file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
    ], function (customerData) {
        'use strict';

        customerData.get('cart').subscribe(function (cartInfo) {
            console.log(cartInfo['summary_count']);
        }, this);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, let me try this.

Comment: Will it work for guest user also?

Comment: yes it will work.............

Comment: Yes, Thanks Its working fine for me.