# How to display the cart number on each page?

Tags: cart, magento2.4

I am having an issue,How to display the cart number on each page?

```
$helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
echo $helper->getItemsCount();
```

or

```
$helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart::class');
echo $helper->getSummaryCount();
```

Can only be displayed on the shopping cart page, and still displays 0 on other pages

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37134703/magento-2-how-to-get-cart-items-total-in-header-phtml

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300135/how-to-get-summary-count-in-phtml-file

Comment: are you using block file or directly on phtml file?

Comment: used phtml file

Comment: I post the answer, if it help upvote and accepted as solution, so it will help other in community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
    ], function (customerData) {
        'use strict';

        customerData.get('cart').subscribe(function (cartInfo) {
            //HERE YOU WANT TO DO THE CODE WHERE YOU WANT TO SHOW THIS
            console.log(cartInfo['summary_count']);
        }, this);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="main.content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom-block-name" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::showcartnumber.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates**

**showcartnumber.phtml**

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$cart_id=$cart->getQuote()->getId();
if ($cart_id) {
    ?>
        <h1>Cart Number : <?php echo $cart_id; ?> </h1>
    <?php
}
?>
```